# Print tags from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, tags

Is there a way to print the tag value I am passing as input to my ansible playbook.
For example, if I pass START as a tag in my playbook payload, How can I print that in the playbook.

I tried using below snippet, but no luck.

```yaml
- name: Display Tags
   debug:
    var: ansible_play_tags
   tags: always
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please define `no luck`. See why ["it does not work" does not help](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) and check how to create a correct [mre]

Comment: Moreover, can you highlight the documentation where you found the variable you used above? Because I see no trace of it in the [ansible special variables documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables). The closest I can read is `ansible_run_tags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_run_tags }}"
```